# Como pasar un dato de Javascript a un input?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo este cronometro y debo pasar el resultado de el tiempo a un input y en este codigo del cronometro cuando lo pongo en marcha aparece un 18 al principio como arreglo eso ejemplo 18:00:00:555

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
var startTime = 0
var start = 0
var end = 0
var diff = 0
var timerID = 0
function chrono(){
    end = new Date()
    diff = end - start
    diff = new Date(diff)
    var msec = diff.getMilliseconds()
    var sec = diff.getSeconds()
    var min = diff.getMinutes()
    var hr = diff.getHours()-1
    if (min < 10){
        min = "0" + min
    }
    if (sec < 10){
        sec = "0" + sec
    }
    if(msec < 10){
        msec = "00" +msec
    }
    else if(msec < 100){
        msec = "0" +msec
    }
    document.getElementById("chronotime").innerHTML = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + ":" + msec
    timerID = setTimeout("chrono()", 10)
}
function chronoStart(){
    document.chronoForm.startstop.value = "stop!"
    document.chronoForm.startstop.onclick = chronoStop
    document.chronoForm.reset.onclick = chronoReset
    start = new Date()
    chrono()
}
function chronoContinue(){
    document.chronoForm.startstop.value = "stop!"
    document.chronoForm.startstop.onclick = chronoStop
    document.chronoForm.reset.onclick = chronoReset
    start = new Date()-diff
    start = new Date(start)
    chrono()
}
function chronoReset(){
    document.getElementById("chronotime").innerHTML = "0:00:00:000"
    start = new Date()
}
function chronoStopReset(){
    document.getElementById("chronotime").innerHTML = "0:00:00:000"
    document.chronoForm.startstop.onclick = chronoStart
}
function chronoStop(){
    document.chronoForm.startstop.value = "start!"
    document.chronoForm.startstop.onclick = chronoContinue
    document.chronoForm.reset.onclick = chronoStopReset
    clearTimeout(timerID)
}
//-->
</script>
```

//////////////////////////////

```
<span id="chronotime">0:00:00:00</span>
<form name="chronoForm">
    <input type="button" name="startstop" value="start!" onClick="chronoStart()" />
    <input type="button" name="reset" value="reset!" onClick="chronoReset()" />
</form>
```

El input

```
<input name="reported_time" type="number" step="0.01" min="0.01" required >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para asignar un valor a un input HTML, debes usar el atributo `value` del elemento:

```js
function asignarValor(){
  document.getElementById('input').value = new Date();
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" style="width: 200px;" placeholder="Asignar Valor" />
<button type="button" onclick="asignarValor()">Asignar valor!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para iniciar en 0, simplemente restale el valor de la hora actual.  Para copiar el valor al input, debes usar `value`.  Toma en cuenta que tu input es de tipo `number`, por lo que solo aceptara numeros.  Asi:

```js
var startTime = 0
var start = 0
var end = 0
var diff = 0
var timerID = 0
function chrono(){
    end = new Date()
    diff = end - start
    diff = new Date(diff)
    var msec = diff.getMilliseconds()
    var sec = diff.getSeconds()
    var min = diff.getMinutes()
    var hr = diff.getHours()-diff.getHours()
    if (min < 10){
        min = "0" + min
    }
    if (sec < 10){
        sec = "0" + sec
    }
    if(msec < 10){
        msec = "00" +msec
    }
    else if(msec < 100){
        msec = "0" +msec
    }
    var time = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + ":" + msec
    var inputTime = min + "." + sec
    document.getElementById("chronotime").innerHTML = time
    document.getElementById("chronoInput").value = inputTime
    timerID = setTimeout("chrono()", 10)
}
function chronoStart(){
    document.chronoForm.startstop.value = "stop!"
    document.chronoForm.startstop.onclick = chronoStop
    document.chronoForm.reset.onclick = chronoReset
    start = new Date()
    chrono()
}
function chronoContinue(){
    document.chronoForm.startstop.value = "stop!"
    document.chronoForm.startstop.onclick = chronoStop
    document.chronoForm.reset.onclick = chronoReset
    start = new Date()-diff
    start = new Date(start)
    chrono()
}
function chronoReset(){
    document.getElementById("chronotime").innerHTML = "0:00:00:000"
    start = new Date()
}
function chronoStopReset(){
    document.getElementById("chronotime").innerHTML = "0:00:00:000"
    document.chronoForm.startstop.onclick = chronoStart
}
function chronoStop(){
    document.chronoForm.startstop.value = "start!"
    document.chronoForm.startstop.onclick = chronoContinue
    document.chronoForm.reset.onclick = chronoStopReset
    clearTimeout(timerID)
}
```

```html
<span id="chronotime">0:00:00:00</span>
<form name="chronoForm">
    <input type="button" name="startstop" value="start!" onClick="chronoStart()" />
    <input type="button" name="reset" value="reset!" onClick="chronoReset()" />
</form>

<input id="chronoInput" name="reported_time" type="number" step="0.01" min="0.01" required >
```