# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar el resultado de una función en un <input> y no en un <div>?

Tags: javascript

hola gusto en saludar tengo mi funcion javascrip y me da el resultad en un div c

como tendria que hacer para que me quede en un input ejemplo

ya que este valor lo enviare por un post

```
// Elimina los diacríticos de un texto excepto si es una "ñ" (ES6)
//
function eliminarDiacriticosEs(texto) {
    return texto
           .normalize('NFD')
           .replace(/([^n\u0300-\u036f]|n(?!\u0303(?![\u0300-\u036f])))[\u0300-\u036f]+/gi,"$1")
           .normalize();
}


//  Prueba

function mostrarSinDiacriticos(inp){
    document.getElementById('muestra')
        .innerText = eliminarDiacriticosEs(inp.value);
}

mostrarSinDiacriticos(texto);
    Texto:
    <input id="texto" oninput="mostrarSinDiacriticos(this)" style="width:100%" value="áéíóúñüÁÉÍÓÚÑÜ">
    Sin Diacríticos:
    <div id="muestra" />
```

Comment: Puedes incluir tu codigo?

Comment: Agrega el codigo en tu pregunta dentro de unos ```. Tambien incluye tu html

Comment: function eliminarDiacriticosEs(texto) {
    return texto
           .normalize('NFD')
           .replace(/([^n\u0300-\u036f]|n(?!\u0303(?![\u0300-\u036f])))[\u0300-\u036f]+/gi,"$1")
           .normalize();
}
function mostrarSinDiacriticos(inp){
    document.getElementById('muestra')
        .innerText = eliminarDiacriticosEs(inp.value);
}
mostrarSinDiacriticos(texto);Texto:
<input id="texto" oninput="mostrarSinDiacriticos(this)" style="width:100%" value="áéíóúñüÁÉÍÓÚÑÜ">
Sin Diacríticos:
<div id="muestra" />

Comment: Dale clic en editar a tu pregunta y pon ese codigo ahi, es mas dificil de leer en un comentario

Comment: quiero tomar ese codigo para eliminar los caracteres especiales q estoy enviado aun fpdf que no me lo acepta qiero eliminarlo cuando el usuario escriba y enviarlos por post

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62031/eliminar-signos-diacr%C3%ADticos-en-javascript-eliminar-tildes-acentos-ortogr%C3%A1ficos

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Como pasar un dato de Javascript a un input?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/203978/como-pasar-un-dato-de-javascript-a-un-input). Ya está explicado en el enlace. Sólo identificas el input por su id y le asignas el dato usando value: `document.getElementById('idDelInput').value = 'El valor a asignar';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

selecciona tu Input

```
var input = document.getElementById('texto')
```

en tu caso el id de:

```
<input id="texto" oninput="mostrarSinDiacriticos(this)" style="width:100%" value="áéíóúñüÁÉÍÓÚÑÜ">
```

y solo le cambias el valor del input

```
input.value = "texto editado por js"
```